# Is the fielding team allowed to place all the fielders in the 30-yard circle?

Tags: rules, cricket

Is the fielding team allowed to place all the fielders in the 30-yard circle?

I know it is allowed in Test cricket as there is nothing like "30-yards" restriction. But is this allowed in other forms of the game?

For example during Powerplay-1 of an ODI match, can the fielding team place all the fielders inside?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, none of the major forms of the game mandate that players *must* be outside the 30 yard circle. Looking for example at the [current (December 2023) men's ODI playing conditions](https://images.icc-cricket.com/image/upload/prd/emgil6d8gwimz8wvvqab.pdf), we can see that the restriction is solely on the number of players outside the 30 yard circle (formally known as the fielding restriction area):

> 28.7.2.2.1 Powerplay 1 - no more than two (2) fielders shall be permitted outside this fielding restriction area. In an innings of 50 overs, these are overs 1 to 10 inclusive.

28.7.2.2.2 and 28.7.2.2.3 deal with powerplay 2 and 3 and have the same form except for the number of players and which overs this applies to. There are similar rules in the [men's T20I playing conditions](https://images.icc-cricket.com/image/upload/prd/vtlex7fs28mukkavtgev.pdf), [women's ODI playing conditions](https://images.icc-cricket.com/image/upload/prd/j1fkpsny6m8ff8gfl6b8.pdf) and [women's T20I playing conditions](https://images.icc-cricket.com/image/upload/prd/ieokwuhg2z0rn6u9ykpd.pdf).

For any other competition, you would need to refer to the playing conditions in force.